# htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, laravel, framework

День добрый. Обновляю Laravel и ловлю эту ошибку (**ErrorException in helpers.php line 531**). Участок кода, который вызывает ошибку :

```
              @if($cases == null)
              <div class="infobox">
              <div class='text-center'>Текст
              </div>
              </div>
              @else
              @foreach($cases as $case)
              <div class="part">
              <div class="p-n"><a href="/cases/{{$case->case_id}}">#{{$case->case_id}}</a></div>
              <div class="p-id">{{$case->case_price}}</div>
              <div class="p-name">
                @if($case->price == 900)
                  {{$case->name}}
                @else
                  {{$case->price}}
                @endif</div>
              <div class="cls"></div>
              </div>
              @endforeach
              @endif
```

По номеру строки в helpers.php стоит следующее:

```
    if (! function_exists('public_path')) {
/**
 * Get the path to the public folder.
 *
 * @param  string  $path
 * @return string
 */
function public_path($path = '')
{
    return app()->make('path.public').($path ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path : $path);
}
}
```

Подскажите возможное решение

Answer (score 0):

ну, сама ошибка говорит, что в функцию ожидалась строка, а передали массив. когда в шаблоне вы указываете вывод переменной в {{  }}, то принудительно применяется обработка данной переменной htmlentities(). видимо, одна из переменных - массив.
советую просто продампить отправляемые в шаблон данные и увидеть в реальности, что в них находится